# Python - webscraping to go several depth-levels within a page with requests module

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have a Python3 script that is performing web scraping based on the urls provided in a csv file.
I am trying to achieve the following:

1.) Get a page from the URL provided in the CSV file

2.) Scrape it and search for email addresses with regex + beautifulsoup, then, if email is found, save it to a results.csv file

3.) Search for all other  (links) on the page

4.) Go to/get all the links found in the 1st page (1st level of scraping) and do the same

5.) Perform the same based on the user's defined level of depth (if the user would say go 3 levels deeper than it would do this: Get the page from 1st level (url from CSV file) and do what is needed on that page -> Get all the pages from 2nd level (scraped links from 1st level) and do what is needed -> Get all the pages from 3rd level (scraped links from 2nd level) and do what is needed -> and so on...

How do I create a loop which would take care of the depth-level scraping?
I have tried playing with multiple variants of for and while loops, but I am unable to come up with a working solution.

This is the code that I currently have (currently it's only able to take care of the 1st level scraping):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import re

import time
import sys, os

#Type the amount of max level of depth for this instance of script
while True:
    try:
        max_level_of_depth = int(input('Max level of depth for webscraping (must be a number - integer): '))
        print('Do not open the input and neither the output CSV files before the script finishes!')
        break
    except:
        print('You must type a number (integer)! Try again...\n')
        
#Read the csv file with urls
with open('urls.csv', mode='r') as urls:
    #Loop through each url from the csv file
    for url in urls:
        #Strip the url from empty new lines
        url_from_csv_to_scrape = url.rstrip('\n')
        print('[FROM CSV] Going to ' + url_from_csv_to_scrape)
        #time.sleep(3)
        i = 1
        #Get the content of the webpage
        page = requests.get(url_from_csv_to_scrape)
        page_content = page.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_content, 'lxml')
        #Find all <p> tags on the page
        paragraphs_on_page = soup.find_all('p')
        for paragraph in paragraphs_on_page:
            #Search for email address in the 1st level of the page
            emails = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}', str(paragraph))
            #If some emails are found on the webpage, save them to csv
            if emails:
                with open('results.csv', mode='a') as results:
                    for email in emails:
                        print(email)
                        if email.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.JPG', '.JPEG', '.PNG')):
                            continue
                        results.write(url_from_csv_to_scrape + ', ' + email + '\n')
                        print('Found an email. Saved it to the output file.\n')
                    results.close()
        #Find all <a> tags on the page
        links_on_page = soup.find_all('a')
        #Initiate a list with all links which will later be populated with all found urls to be crawled
        found_links_with_href = []
        #Loop through all the <a> tags on the page
        for link in links_on_page:
            try:
                #If <a> tag has href attribute
                if link['href']:
                    link_with_href = link['href']
                    #If the link from the webpage does not have domain and protocol in it, prepend them to it
                    if re.match(r'https://', link_with_href) is None and re.match(r'http://', link_with_href) is None:
                        #If the link already has a slash in it, remove it because it will be added after prepending
                        link_with_href = re.sub(r'/', '', link_with_href)
                        #Prepend the domain and protocol in front of the link
                        link_with_href = url_from_csv_to_scrape + link_with_href
                        #print(link_with_href)
                    found_links_with_href.append(link_with_href)
                    found_links_with_href_backup = found_links_with_href
            except:
                #If <a> tag does not have href attribute, continue
                print('No href attribute found, going to next <a> tag...')
                continue
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: for this task use `scrapy`, see: https://scrapy.org/

Comment: I will be deploying this script on a VM on which using scrapy library is prohibited. I have to use requests and beautifulsoup for this script.. Can not use anything else apart from the libraries I already imported in the code that I posted.

Comment: @rogatoo in that case create loop that will find all links in page and perform function on new founded links

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi not sure what you mean exactly. i already have a for loop to iterate through the URLs from my CSV file. Not sure how to create an inner loop to just iterate a finite times (based on user’s input) to go deeper in the page..

Comment: use `while any url link found on page -> do something -> check if new links are found`

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi yes, essentially that is what I already have. The issue is, that then I do not know how to proceed `if new links are found`.

Comment: you don't created while loop for searching for new url, you set some data from input, that is not the solution to do this.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Hmm, I'm not sure I understand then. Would it be possible for you to just write a basic precise structure of the loops I shall use, please? Something like `for url in csv -> scrape it -> while loop for something -> another loop for something else` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221801/discussion-between-rogaloo-and-zaraki-kenpachi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some pseudo code:

```
def find_page(page):
    new = re.findall('regex', page.text)
    new_pages.append(new)
    return len(new)

check = True
new_pages = [page]
used_pages = []
while check:

    for item in new_pages:
        if item not in used_pages:
            found = find_page(item)
            if found == 0:
                check = False
            else:
                'find emails'
            
        used_pages.append(item)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! This, however, is not able to handle a loop which iterations will be defined by user (if he says 2, than it should also loop through the links found from the 1st page and scrape them as well)

Comment: @rogaloo this should scrape emails from all founded pages. you don't need to specify any input from user

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned in my original post, I need to be able to determine the depth-level of scraping. Specifically (copied from my original post):

Get the page from 1st level (url from CSV file) and do what is needed on that page -> Get all the pages from 2nd level (scraped links from 1st level) and do what is needed -> Get all the pages from 3rd level (scraped links from 2nd level) and do what is needed -> and so on (stopping on the depth-level/number defined by user)

Comment: @rogaloo then you need specify how the program will define the level for you. If by level you mean sub page then you need to check current url for level position.